# Handling multiple projects in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to handle in one time multiple projects in Visual Studio (SteamVR, Obi). Problem only occures in Visual Studio, in Unity Editor everything works fine.

My projects in Visual Studio 2019 look like this:

[image: Project Explorer]

Now, I want to write code in main project script which will connect all projects. Code:

```
using Obi;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Rendering;
using Valve.VR.InteractionSystem;

public class ObiURPSteamVR : MonoBehaviour
{
    //1 - Obi - no problem in Unity, VS error in declaration
    public ObiEmitter emitter;

    //2 - URP Volume - working
    public Volume URPVolume;

    //3 - SteamVR - no problem in Unity, VS error in declaration AND in "using"
    public Player steamVRPlayer;

}
```

[image: Errors in picture]

My question is how to connect all projects, is it possible? And i will just add one more time, in Unity Editor everything is working, i can drag-drop SteamVR player and ObiEmitter, no errors are in console output. Thanks for every idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently its a bug in Unity 2019.3.12f version. Checked on 2019.4.01f and everything is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, create an "empty solution". Add all your projects to this solution. When one project is referencing types from another project, right click on that project and "Add Reference".

Comment: In Unity Project you cannot "Add Reference", this option isnt showing up when working in Unity.

Comment: What about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48875798/add-reference-is-missing-in-visual-studio-when-using-with-unity-3d-need-npgsql

Comment: Hm, so i checked references as there are in the post, and theoretically there are ticks next to rest of projects. Although, i got .asmdef which are defining where projects are, not .dll files. But it's some start.