# How can I use HtmlAgilityPack in Unity?

Tags: c#, html, unity-game-engine, html-agility-pack

Can't get HtmlAgilityPack in my Unity project, hopefully someone here can figure out what I'm doing wrong and help me out.

What I did this far:

- Installed NuGet in Microsoft Studio
- Installed HtmlAgilityPack v1.11.26 (most recent) using NuGet (check screenshot) in my Unity 2020.1.10f project (it added a "HtmlAgilityPack.1.11.26" folder on my Unity Project / Packages)
- Got "using HtmlAgilityPack;" on top of my script (check screenshot)
- Tried deleting Library folder so Unity rebuilds it (nothing changes)
- Tried both .NET Standard 2.0 and .NET 4.x in Unity> Edit> ProjectSettings> Player> API Compatibility Level

Current Error on adding the library:
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HtmlAgilityPack' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Screenshot of Unity not recognizing library:

[image: Screenshot of Unity not recognizing library]

Screenshot of Microsoft Studio NuGet with `HtmlAgilityPack` installed:

[image: Screenshot of Microsoft Studio NuGet with HtmlAgilityPack installed]

Comment: Check that HtmlAgilityPack has been added to the References in your Visual Studio project. If not right click on "References" in the solution explorer, select "Add Reference", find and add HtmlAgilityPack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Check that `HtmlAgilityPack` has been added to the References in your Visual Studio project.
If not right click on "References" in the solution explorer, select "Add Reference", find and add `HtmlAgilityPack` ([advice by Jon P](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64659870/how-can-i-use-htmlagilitypack-in-unity#comment114350466_64659870)).

To me, when right clicking "References" the option "Add Reference" wasn't showing up. I solved this problem looking at the first answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48875798).

When adding `HtmlAgilityPack` on my unity project (using NuGet) I noticed it added a `HtmlAgilityPack.1.11.26` folder on my Unity Project/Packages.
So I went to `HtmlAgilityPack.1.11.26 /lib/Net45` and copied everything (including `.dll`s) to the Plugins folder as the link said. Since I copied the `.dll` from the Net45 folder I updated the project to ".NET 4.x" (as explained above).

Adding the `.dll`s to the `Plugins` folder automatically added the reference on my project and solved the problem of missing reference.