# Html Agility Pack and Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, html-agility-pack, jetbrains-rider

I want to use HTML Agility Pack in unity;
I also use rider; My first idea was to use the rider installed packages; This works in rider and rider compiles but the moment that I start it in unity it cannot find the package;
I have instead tried to copy all of the data from HtmlAgilityPack into Assets\Plugins. This also does not work; Does anyone know which file I need to copy and where or know of a guide that can help me?

Comment: Answer can be found in this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64659870/how-can-i-use-htmlagilitypack-in-unity

Answer (score 0):

Use the Standard Library build of html agility pack.

Comment: Could provide code example

Comment: I see ways to download the raw nupkg file. I see multiple ways to get it(PM CLI PR Cake). Where do I get the standard library build or how do I go from the nupkg file to the standard library build