# Unity 2021.2.8f1 Can't use other assemblies with my scripts and can't add reference through visual studio either

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Downloaded an A star pathfinding package from https://arongranberg.com/astar/download and imported it into unity. It is working completely fine but when I try accessing the namespace Pathfinding from it, it can't find the right namespace. [Errors caused by assembly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pu24.png).

I tried searching for other solutions and tried to implement this one. [Add Reference is missing in Visual Studio when using with Unity 3D - Need Npgsql.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48875798/add-reference-is-missing-in-visual-studio-when-using-with-unity-3d-need-npgsql)
This fixed the error lines in visual studio but doesn't change anything in Unity itself
[Works in visual studio but not in unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYZeU.png).

The version of visual studio is 2019 and unity is 2021.2.8f1

Comment: There is no “the” a star path finding. It will have documentation and examples. They will tell you what is wrong

Comment: my bad should've specified, ill edit my answer now

Comment: Since the error logs are shown in Unity then Visual Studio has nothing to do with it, if you can't access that type on your scripts then maybe you're missing a "using" directive.
It would help a lot if you shared the scripts that are outputing those errors.

Comment: If their examples work you need to check what is missing in your code.

Comment: @AntônioPedro In the images that i posted, they are both caused by the same script. In the videos and documentation, they all require a Using Pathfinding; line that I do have but unity does not seem to recognize it.

Comment: @BugFinder thats the thing, I really cannot. In a brackets tutorial in 2019 unity, I even copied his video line by line but I don't think the code's the problem

Answer (score 0):

Okay managed to fix the errors. A long time ago, I randomly made an assembly definition asset in unity. Once I deleted that and reloaded visual studio, the errors disappeared.